# Multiple Facebook Like Buttons Same Page URL

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, hashtag

I want to have multiple Facebook Like Buttons on a single page, all pointing to the same URL. My understanding of the Like Button is that you are liking the URL of the page. But, say for example I have a page with several product attributes, maybe a t-shirt in different colors (Red, Blue, Green, etc.). Each of these colors does not have it's own URL.

Is it possible to like the same URL multiple times? Person likes Red Shirt, Person Likes Blue Shirt, etc.

I attempted to do this with hashtags, yet this did not work. Initial thoughts were to dynamically change the Open Graph Meta tags via Javascript, but A) that doesn't combat the issue of the same URL, and B) that would only work assuming the Facebook API pulls the information from the Meta tags immediately after the click, and not on initial page load or with a separate remote call.

Any ideas?

NOTE: I can not append a query string to the url (i.e. mysite.com/t-shirt?color=red )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really consider creating a single page for every product.

This will bring you additional benefits:
- images and product links in the news feed;
- much better seo for the single product;
- much better seo for your website.

Are you using a cms?

**EDIT:**

There are a few examples if you google it. But all of them require you to at least create a very basic html page. It's easy and fast.

You can try being more specific about your situation if you need better help.

Comment: Perhaps it was a bad example, but the situation I'm in cannot have multiple pages. So I am looking for a solution on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is dynamic. It uses php. So the address for every button will be the redirecting to the php... something like this:

For the tShirt red:
http://www.yourDomain.com/tshirt.php?color=red

For the tShirt blue:
http://www.yourDomain.com/tshirt.php?color=blue

Put every address in the like button href-param
This work for me every time that i used for multiples Facebook's like buttons.

Comment: And then I would just change the Open Graph Meta data based on the query string to ensure that the correct label/title was being pulled by Facebook?

Is this the only way?